# Sending React Router Page Views to Firebase Analytics

Tags: firebase, react-router, firebase-analytics

My app uses React Router's `BrowserRouter`. How can I track page views and send them to google firebase analytics (I've already installed `firebase-analytics.js`).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just render the following component anywhere inside your `<BrowserRouter>`:

```js
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { useEffect } from "react";

function FirebaseAnalytics() {
    const location = useLocation();
    useEffect(() => {
        const analytics = window.firebase && window.firebase.analytics;
        if (typeof analytics === "function") {
            const page_path = location.pathname + location.search;
            analytics().setCurrentScreen(page_path);
            analytics().logEvent("page_view", { page_path });
        }
    }, [location]);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: `setCurrentScreen` is deprecated. It's better to use only the logEvent method.
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.analytics.Analytics#setcurrentscreen

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative / additional consideration to Tzach's answer, you may prefer to import firebase and set

```
const analytics = firebase.analytics;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using **React + TypeScript** some type errors will appear.
Also, in my opinion, it is better to use a React Hook because in this case you are adding logic to a component (not another component). I leave my proposal down below:

```js
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { getAnalytics, logEvent } from '@firebase/analytics';

export function useFirebaseRoutesAnalytics() {
    const location = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
        const analytics = getAnalytics();
        logEvent(analytics, 'screen_view', {
            firebase_screen: location.pathname, // <- In my case I do not want to include search params, so 'location.pathname' is just what I want
            firebase_screen_class: 'firebase-routes-analytics', // <- This name is up to you
        });
    }, [location]);

    return null;
}
```